# Mapping a hierarchy of entities to a hierarchy of DTOs using Orika

Tags: java, orika, object-object-mapping

Is it possible to map an object to its corrisponding DTO when both belonging to a class hierarchy?

For example: I have a `BaseEntity` and some `ExtendedEntity1` .. `ExtendedEntityN`

On the other side I have a `BaseDTO` and some `ExtendedDTO1` .. `ExtendedDTON`

Then I have a service method:

```
public BaseDTO getById(String id) {
    return orikaMapper.map(repository.findOne(id), BaseDTO.class);
}
```

This way I'am obviously getting always a `BaseDTO`, but I'd like to map the entity to the right DTO type...

Is there a way to achieve this? I wouldn't to use `switch` or `instanceof`-check workarounds...

Comment: This is an old question but you might want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225565/1505146) to a very similar question. The underlying issue is not tied to Orika or Spring or Mapstruct so I believe my comment is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet discovered a better solution (if one exists), so I'll go this way:

```
Map<Class<? extends BaseEntity>, Class<? extends BaseDTO>> dtoMappings;
```

I'm defining a mappings `Map` where I put all the associations between entities and DTOs. Then in my method:

```
public BaseDTO getById(String id) {
    BaseEntity e = repository.findOne(id);
    return orikaMapper.map(repository.findOne(id), dtoMappings.get(e.getClass()));
}
```